# Oracle Timestamp before 1970 - seconds value incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, seconds

The following SQL run on Oracle 11g returns an incorrect 'seconds' value for dates before 1970-01-01 when fractional seconds are present.

Is there something wrong with the SQL?

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format='SS';

select
       to_timestamp('1969-12-31 23:59:59 0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS FF') TS1,
       to_timestamp('1969-12-31 23:59:59 1','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS FF') TS2,
       to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00 1','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS FF') TS3
from dual;

TS1  TS2  TS3
59   58   00
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit. The result I get is 59, 59, 00. I suggest that you contact Oracle support.

Comment: Might be helpful to know the platform on which you're running Oracle

Comment: @David, The SQL was run on SQL Developer 4.0.0.13, java Platform 1.7.0_45   

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production   
OPATCH_VERSION:11.2.0.3.6  
 
MS Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard   
Service Pack 1

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the question to Oracle Support

Comment: I have found that the correct results are produced in SQL+

Comment: i am unable to reproduce this eitehr. sql developer 4.1.3.20.78 connected to oracle 11.2.0.1